# Nested View's Presenter not getting initialized and not being able to handle its view's events

Tags: java, gwt, guice, gwt-gin, mvp4g

I am facing an issue, when I do inject a nested view  into my base view's constructor using @inject. I am not able to handle the nested view's events in it own presenter. Because  of which I need to handle them in the Base View's presenter.
I have 2 view and their respective presenter's : AppBaseView - AppBasePresenter;
LoginView - LoginPresenter.
I @inject LoginView into the AppBaseView.
Now that I have to handle the Login Button event, I am not able to do so in the LoginPresenter, but need to handle it in the AppBasePresenter.
No idea why does that happen. Am I missing anything?
Any light on this issue would be higly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide any sample code? What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to inject the same view into multiple classes, remember that you have to mark it as `@Singleton`, or otherwise ensure that both classes receive the same instance. By default Guice and Gin create a brand new instance every time you inject a class. It's hard to tell from your description, but you might be adding an event listener to an instance that the presenter owns and then displaying a *different* instance in your application.